# Facebook doesn't notify me after the user grants extended permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions, notifications, facebooker

I am developing a Facebook App which requires some extended permission. The problem is that Facebook doesn't automatically ping my app when those permissions are granted by the user. I have to manually query for them or the user must press a confirmation button to send them to me.

My question is how can I enable Facebook to ping me automatically when permissions are changed. I am using the Facebooker plugin in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a canvas application when a user has granted extended permissions you will begin to receive a parameter specifying which permissions were granted (fb_sig_ext_perms).

You can also use the FBJS function Facebook.showPermissionsDialog which will execute a callback that tells you which permissions the user has granted. Documentation here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook.showPermissionDialog

For Facebook connect, you can specify a javascript callback for when the user has granted (or chosen not to grant) permission. Documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog